Fatal Error with BlockArts Block Plugin on WordPress – Cannot Traverse an Already Closed Generator
I am facing an issue with the BlockArts Block plugin on my WordPress / WooCommerce site. Recently, I started encountering the following fatal error when attempting to edit any pages or blocks built using the plugin:
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Cannot traverse an already closed generator in /var/www/vhosts/flawxmusic.com/academy.flawxmusic.com/wp-content/plugins/blockart-blocks/includes/ScriptStyle.php:358

This error prevents me from modifying any content on the site, essentially breaking my ability to edit pages or blocks.
Details:

The issue appeared suddenly without any prior warnings.
I have not made any major recent changes to the site, except for updating some basic plugins.
The error is occurring specifically in the ScriptStyle.php file on line 358.
The plugin was functioning perfectly well before this issue surfaced.

Steps I’ve Taken:

Deactivated and reactivated the plugin: This did not resolve the issue, and the error persisted when attempting to edit pages.
Cleared the cache: I cleared the WordPress and server cache using the WP Super Cache plugin, deleting all files from the cache directory. This did not resolve the issue because the error persists when I attempt to edit a page.
Tried modifying the plugin code: Based on a suggestion from Chat-GPT, I attempted changes to the plugin code to fix the error. While this removed the error message, it caused all blocks to break and display incorrectly.
Checked for other changes: No changes to themes or other plugins have been made that could have affected the BlockArts plugin.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with this plugin? What might be causing this fatal error, and how can I resolve it without losing access to the content created with BlockArts Block?
Any guidance or suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!
